# Ng-if not hiding element when watched variable turns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to hide an element based on the width of the screen and a test variable. I am running into an edge case where the ng-if directive is not properly hiding an element despite the value being false. Here are the relevant code snippets. The console log reports that my elemnt should be visible, however it is not showing up.

```
$scope.setContents = function(contents) {
    $scope.noteContent=contents;
    $scope.noteVisible=true;
    $scope.hideNoteList();
  }

$scope.checkWindowSize = function() {
    if ( $(window).innerWidth() < 768 ) {
      $scope.smallScreen = true;
      console.log("Window size is small");
      $scope.hideNoteList();
    }
    else {
      $scope.smallScreen = false;
      console.log("Window size is not small");
      $scope.hideNoteList();
    }
  }

$scope.hideNoteList = function () {
    if($scope.smallScreen && $scope.noteVisible){
      $scope.noteListVisible= false;
      console.log("Note List Should be Hiding");
    }
    else {
      console.log("Note List Should be Visible");
      $scope.noteListVisible= true;
    }
  }

$(window).load($scope.checkWindowSize);
  $(window).resize($scope.checkWindowSize);
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-group col-xs-0 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" ng-if="noteListVisible">
<li ng-repeat="note in notes>
  <h2 ng-click="setContents(note.content)"></h2>
</li>
```

Comment: what triggers `$scope.checkWindowSize`?

Comment: Forgot to add those two lines. Its Jquery's .resize method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that jQuery events are triggered outside of Angular digest cycle, so you need to call `$scope.$apply` manually.

```
$(window).load(jqCheckWindowSize);
$(window).resize(jqCheckWindowSize);

function jqCheckWindowSize() {
  $scope.$apply($scope.checkWindowSize);
}
```

Or in a poweruser two lines way:

```
$(window).load  ($scope.$apply.bind($scope, $scope.checkWindowSize));
$(window).resize($scope.$apply.bind($scope, $scope.checkWindowSize));
```

Alternatively, you can call `$scope.$apply` directly in `checkWindowSize` or wrap the code using `$timeout`, etc. Many answers here already cover this.

Comment: Confirmed that it works. I'm ecstatic for the help, I knew something had to be missing!

Comment: Cool :) however if your app becomes big be aware that a `$scope.$apply` on every window resize event can be quite costly and slows things down (during the resize). You may want to check `throttle` (via underscore/lodash or a jquery plugin or just add some timeouts) to check that only every few milliseconds